# BIOS like, interactive menu, for python text based game

Tags: python, python-3.x, bios

I am writing a text based game in python and as you'd expect, it has many questions with multiple answers e.g. yes/no.

I have been been using the usual, input your answer, answering technique, but I was hoping to make it a bit more interactive in answering some options, such as the main menu. I do not want a full on GUI but is there some way to have something similar to, for example, the modern BIOS menu, where you use the arrow keys to navigate, and press enter to select?

http://www.washington.edu/lst1/help/computing_fundamentals/troubleshootingxp/img/bios.gif

Thanks for any reply's, whether it's possible or not!

P.S. I would rather not have to download any plugins etc, because I have to be able to use this at school where I cannot use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rather open-ended question (not have to download any "plugins")?  But what you want is the curses library, to which Python has an interface with its `curses` module.  The Python docs provide a [simple tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html) for using it.

There is also a library called [Blessings](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blessings/) which provides a nicer, more modern object-oriented interface to curses.  I haven't tried it but it's well supported and looks pretty good.

Comment: I always liked the name of this module.. "What are you using?" "Curses!"

Comment: Perhaps I'm slow, but it actually took me a while to "get" the name of "blessings".  It does sound more pleasant to use, doesn't it?  Though "curses" just comes from something having to do with "cursors".

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the Urwid library: http://excess.org/urwid/

(I know you'd like to not use an external module, but that means you'll essentially have to reimplement most of CURSES yourself, and that's a road you really don't want to take)